# How do I add an empty directory in Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, architecture, directory

I want to be able to set up a Git repository with various folders that will later be populated with files.

The idea being that one developer creates the source control layout, while other developers populate the repository with usable files.

Comment: I looked at all the suggested duplicates and nothing quite matched.
The accepted solution to the question linked is also not even correct as it then ignores all files that are subsequently added to said folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to accomplish this is by adding a simple empty file within each directory. Since this is being hosted on GitHub (Enterprise in my case), a very useful file to have around is a README.md file.

Obviously, you could then put whatever markdown you want in each of those README files to describe the contents at each layer of the repository. For just getting the folders to show up though, an empty README shall suffice.